# How to handle objects with length of one and greater than one in a method without redunancy

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my own JavaScript bind method (for practice) and am having trouble letting go of the need to handle single objects vs multiple objects differently in this method, solely because I need to loop through objects with a length greater than one. (see obj vs obj[i] below)

**Is there any way I can make this bind method less redundant feeling?** (please assume using another library is out of the question.. thanks)

```
var foo = (function () {
    return {
        bind: function (obj, type, handler, delegate) {
            var delegate = delegate || false,
                len = obj.length;
            if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {
                return false;
            }
            if (len > 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (obj.addEventListener) {
                        obj[i].addEventListener(type, handler, delegate); // false: bubble (^). true: capture (v).
                    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                        obj[i].attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
                    } else {
                        obj[i]['on' + type] = handler;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (obj.addEventListener) {
                    obj.addEventListener(type, handler, delegate); // false: bubble (^). true: capture (v).
                } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                    obj.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
                } else {
                    obj['on' + type] = handler;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Your code won't work for single-element arrays.

Comment: I had originally setup getElementByClass() methods to return the actual object if it had a length of one. starting to think this was a stupid idea now. Doing that basically created the need to run this check that you guys are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat obj with an empty array:

```
obj = [].concat(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force it into an array:

```
if (!('length' in obj))
    obj = [ obj ];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].addEventListener) {
        obj[i].addEventListener(type, handler, delegate); // false: bubble (^). true: capture (v).
    } else if (obj[i].attachEvent) {
        obj[i].attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
    } else {
        obj[i]['on' + type] = handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 in 20 minutes, when I get my votes back... (Even though I dislike your omission of curly brackets on the if statement.)

Answer (score 1):

You could test `obj` to see if it has a `nodeType` property. If so, place it in an Array.

```
if( obj.nodeType ) {
    obj = [ obj ];
    //...
```

or you could do a concat on an empty Array.

```
obj = [].concat(obj);
```

This will give you an Array if you don't have one.

---

So your final code could look like this:

```
var foo = (function () {
    return {
        bind: function (obj, type, handler, delegate) {
            var delegate = delegate || false
            if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {
                return false;
            }
            obj = [].concat(obj);
            for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (obj[i].addEventListener) {
                    obj[i].addEventListener(type, handler, delegate); // false: bubble (^). true: capture (v).
                } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                    obj[i].attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
                } else {
                    obj[i]['on' + type] = handler;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding your code, I would say that if you have only 1 object it should still be contained within an array, and thus one single iteration would occur. There should be no need to cater for the singular case.

You should check for the singular case and convert it to an array with a single entry:

```
if (obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") == -1) {
    obj = [obj];
}
```

Comment: Right, I was assuming he could work out that if the object is singular, to convert it into an array. I will modify accordingly.